# AutoStart Application at login in unity 15.10

Tags: unity, login, 15.10

With Ubuntu 15.10 wiley werewolf in Unity there is no more "startup applications" in the dash or else.

But fortunately after upgrading from 15.04 my startup-applications still startup! :-)

Where can i change the settings?

Answer (score 1):

Better and complete is the configuration of startup-applications in files:

For each application create a file in

> ~/.config/autostart

with the ".desktop" suffix. do it like this from the terminal:

> gedit  ~/.config/autostart/unison.desktop

And use this template for the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=unison -batch robert-desktop_pub
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[de_DE]=unison
Name=unison
Comment[de_DE]=unison -batch robert-desktop_pub
Comment=unison -batch robert-desktop_pub
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "gnome-session-properties" in the dash, which is the non-localized name and thus safely finds the correct german "Startapplikationen".

Also you can partially use "gnome-tweak-tool" which you can find easily in the dash.